# Seeking for Faster PDF/A Verification Tool in Django

Tags: django, pdfa

I am currently working on a Django project that involves PDF file uploading and checking whether the uploaded file is PDF/A compliant. To accomplish this, I have been using an external module, VeraPDF.

However, the verification process with VeraPDF takes around 3 seconds, which I find to be quite long.

Therefore, I'm reaching out to the community for suggestions on any other free external modules or libraries that could potentially speed up this PDF/A verification process in a Django environment.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Asynchronous Batch Processing for PDF/A Verification in Django

====================================================================
Parsing XML Directly in the Service Layer vs Using VeraPDF for PDF/A Verification

In our current Django project, we're considering two different approaches to verifying whether a PDF is compliant with PDF/A.

The first approach involves directly parsing the XML of the PDF in the service layer of our application to check for the presence of PDF/A attributes. The second approach involves continuing to use the VeraPDF tool, which we are currently using, but which takes approximately three seconds to verify a single file.

Both methods have their potential advantages and drawbacks. Directly parsing the XML could potentially offer more control and efficiency, but it would also require developing and maintaining additional code. Using VeraPDF, on the other hand, requires less code but the verification time is longer than we'd prefer.

I'm interested in hearing the community's thoughts on these options. Is it more efficient to develop custom code for directly parsing the PDF's XML in the service layer, or is it better to continue using a tool like VeraPDF? Are there any considerations or trade-offs that I might be missing?

Your insights and recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.